# Как узнать количество ячеек в секции?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Как узнать количество ячеек в секции в которой находится выбранная ячейка через метод tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дернуть - `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` у датасурса (обычно тот же класс), номер секции указан в `IndexPath`

Comment: А как например поменять Accessory у 3 ячейки в 5 секции?

Comment: что-то типа
   
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:5];

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.accessoryView = ...

Answer (score 4):

Вы НЕ должны смотреть на количество секций. ячеек в них и вообще ячеек. Это все вьюхи.

Вы должны смотреть себе в модель, чтобы это понять, и вообще понять что и как у вас.
Например, если у вас есть массив где вы берете данные, смотрите количество предметов в нем, или если у вас каждая секция в своем массиве, смотрите в них.

Ответ по существу:

[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1];

Где 1 - номер секции.